# embed my two latest youtube uploads on my site using javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that there have been older answers to this question but I cant seem to find one that currently works. I want to be able to have my two latest uploads displayed on my website so users can watch them right there and not have to go to youtube. I have no code currently since I have no clue as to how this would be done.

Comment: You're looking for the YouTube API.

Comment: Maybe this might help you? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

Comment: @NewToJs I have already tried the youtubeAPI but I just started learning Javascript last week. I have progressed a lot but I am not ready for youtubeAPI since I dont understand half of it. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe if you don't want to use the youtubeAPI(harder for a novice) :

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I think the idea is to display the two latest videos and have them update as the uploads on the youtube account has been altered with new uploads without having to open the website source code and modify the iframes every time a new video is added.

Answer (score 0):

without API, show playlist (latest video)

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list={username}"></iframe>
```

with API, javascript

```
<div id="myvideo"></div>
```

`maxResults=2` limit 2 result video

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={your_channelId}&maxResults=2&order=date&type=video&key={API_KEY}',
  success: function(response, status) {
    for(var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
      var video = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + response.items[i].id.videoId + '"></iframe>';
      $("#myvideo").append(video);
    }
  }
})
```